# authentication for custom web application with mod_auth_openidc

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-auth-openidc

I have a basic web application which runs on apache 2.2 and doesn't have any authentication. The site content is a static webpage.
Our small organization is currently working on implementing *mod_auth_openidc* for all the websites.
I wanted to implement *mod_auth_openidc* authentication on top of basic static web application.

How can I achieve it?
I am newbie to apache configuration and *mod_auth_openidc*. I Googled around for some articles to implement it but I couldn't find any. I have created a static account for my application on Oauth2 server.

Can someone point me in right direction on how to enable authentication for my static web page application with *mod_auth_openidc* and *mod_proxy* configuration?

```
<Location />
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require valid-user
</Location>
OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://example.com/fss/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID ExampleCorp_Prod_web01
OIDCClientSecret <client-secret>
OIDCRedirectURI http://<ip>/redirect_uri
OIDCScope "profile openid"
OIDCCryptoPassphrase example@3003
OIDCCookiePath /
ProxyPass /  http://<ip>:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse / http://<ip>:8080/
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes on
<Proxy http://<ip>:8080/*>
</Proxy>
OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User
OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
OIDCClaimPrefix example_
LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so
```

Comment: what provider would you configure against?

Comment: Hi Hans, We are using pingfederate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are examples in the README on the Github project pages: https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc. Assuming the static webpages lives on `/example`, in your specific (PingFederate) example it would be something like:

```
OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://<pingfederate-host>:9031/.well-known/openid-configuration

OIDCClientID <client-id-as-registered-with-pingfederate>
OIDCClientSecret <client-secret-as-registered-with-pingfederate>

OIDCRedirectURI https://<your-apache-host>/example/redirect_uri/
OIDCCryptoPassphrase <password>
OIDCScope "openid email profile"

<Location /example/>
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

A complete working example based on the OPs environment:

```
Listen 80
User www
Group www
DocumentRoot /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel info
ServerName example.org

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule authz_user_module   modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<Location />
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require valid-user
</Location>

OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID myclientid
OIDCClientSecret mysecret
OIDCRedirectURI http://example.org/protected/
OIDCScope "profile openid"
OIDCCryptoPassphrase example@3003
OIDCCookiePath /

ProxyPass /  http://192.168.10.1:80/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.10.1:80/
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes on
<Proxy http://192.168.10.1:8080/*>
</Proxy>

OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User
OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
OIDCClaimPrefix example_
```

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for the information provided. I am trying to use a hello world page behind the openidc login. I have used an example from openidc wiki 10.

Comment: i am using the below url for configuring a hello world web page with mod_auth_openidc+mod_proxy+hello world program https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/wiki#10-can-you-show-me-a-simple-application. but i am seeing "401 authorization error"

Comment: and logs show me oidc_unsolicited_proto_state: could not parse JWT from state: invalid unsolicited response: [src/jose/apr_jwt.c:177: apr_jwt_base64url_decode_object]: JSON parsing (json_loads) failed: '[' or '{' expected near 'l' (l\\\xb4\xe7r\x12\x97\xec\x0e\x1d\xea\xde\x8az\xe5|\xccb\xf0\xcd)\n  oidc_authorization_response_match_state: unable to restore state  oidc_handle_authorization_response: invalid authorization response state and no default SSO URL is set, sending an error...  very sorry for the mixed log and short comments. I am unable to create a next line at each comment

Comment: don't access the redirect_uri directly; that's a vanity URL that is used only by the module itself

Comment: Oh my bad, thank you..almost there... i have correct the url i am hitting now. but i still see "Authrization error 401" and i have set up loglevel to debug. but i dont see any errors related to oidc now.. but when i disable oidc config template and httpd restart. i see the hello world back. Do i have to setup any basic authentication on static webpage? please suggest

Comment: <Location />
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require valid-user
</Location>
OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://example.com/fss/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID ExampleCorp_test01
OIDCClientSecret <client-secret-here>
OIDCRedirectURI http://ip/redirect_uri
OIDCScope "profile openid"
OIDCCryptoPassphrase example
OIDCCookiePath /
ProxyPass /  http://ip:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip:8080/
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes on
<Proxy http://ip:8080/*>
</Proxy>
OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User
OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
OIDCClaimPrefix example_

Comment: please modify your original question with your config

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment, updated the question with config content

Comment: that config works for me; I've added a complete minimal example to the answer

Comment: I have verified the same config on jenkins http header based authentication and it was working for me, but when i am using the same config for a static html page like "hello world", its showing "401 authorization required", there is no error in the log found.

Comment: it must be something else in your env that conflicts then; please try with the minimal complete example as I provided

Comment: You are Perfect Hans!!! There was a external port issue. the problem is stuck at proxying withing the machine. anyhow, i tried with another url and i found the above config is working fine. Thank you so much for the wonderful application and support Hans Z!